# Create a list of users joining or leaving a group in a sequence using PySpark

Tags: python, database, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe like below

| id | action | group | timestmp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | join | grp1 | 2021-07-24 12:01:19.000 |
| 1 | leave | grp1 | 2021-07-24 12:01:20.000 |
| 1 | join | grp1 | 2021-07-24 12:01:21.000 |
| 2 | leave | grp2 | 2021-07-24 12:01:19.000 |
| 2 | join | grp3 | 2021-07-24 12:01:19.000 |
| 2 | join | grp4 | 2021-07-24 12:01:19.000 |

I want to process these events serially(timestmp), and come up with below. Is there a way to do this in Pyspark? Any help is appreciated.

| id | join | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [grp1] |  |
| 2 | [grp3,grp4] | [grp2] |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was:

```
df1 = df1
  .orderBy(col("timestamp").desc)
  .groupBy("id", "group").agg(last("action").as("last_action"))
  .groupBy("id").pivot("last_action").agg(collect_set("group"))
```

Basically, first we order on the `timestamp`, then we get the last action, we pivot the created last action and the final output:

```
+---+------------+------+
|id |join        |leave |
+---+------------+------+
|1  |[grp1]      |[]    |
|2  |[grp4, grp3]|[grp2]|
+---+------------+------+
```

which is I hope what you need, good luck!